# Laravel policy always returns 403 despite user role being correct

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm working on a Laravel 8 project that has customers and admins. Admins are allowed to view data within my `ManagementController` if their role is a `superadmin`. I've got a `role` column as a `enum` value on my `users` table, and have registered my policy, but it always returns 403 and my message regardless of the role, what am I doing wrong.

My policy is:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class ManagementPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function view(User $user)
    {
        return $user->role == 'superadmin';
    }
}
```

Registered my policy:

```php
protected $policies = [
    User::class => ManagementPolicy::class
];
```

And then in my `index` function I find out if the user **can't** view the resource, and just return:

```php
if (Auth::user()->cant('view', User::class)) {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'not allowed',
        'role' => Auth::user()->role
    ], 403);
}
```

Comment: try use cannot instead of cant in policy check

Comment: Only seems to work with `Managemnt::class` as the seconds arg, my controller is listed under `app/Http/Controllers/Management/DashboardController` so not sure why it's working with a class that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's using the automatic discovery on policies, not using the one you defined. Make sure you are calling `registerPolicies` in `AppServiceProvider`:

```
/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
}
```

See the laravel docs on auto discovery for more info: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#policy-auto-discovery

Comment: Thanks @erin, I've got `$this->registerPolicies()` in my `boot` function within my `AuthServiceProvider` already? :/

Comment: Hmm... The `protected $policies` should take precedence over the auto discovery then.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought as well, so if I have a policy called `ManagementPolicy`, which I do, Laravel is stripping the `Policy` part and thus that's why `Management::class` works right?

Comment: Does it work if you rename the policy to `UserPolicy`? And do you have a model named `Management`?

Comment: I don't have a model called `Management`, for instances where I simply want to just disallow a user to view a controller action if their user role doesn't equal something, I thought a policy was the way forward with this? I just want to stop someone doing something if their user role doesn't equal what I want

Comment: You can go super simple - `if (auth()->user()->role !== 'superadmin') { abort(403); }`